# Let other apps play background music

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to add the functionality for other apps, such as Pandora or iTunes, to continue playing music while my Sprite Kit game is open.

How would I go about doing this? I apologize for the somewhat broadness of this question, I just can't find a lot of information on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your `AVAudioSession` category to `Ambient`.

```
import AVFoundation

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

[**AVAudioSession Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)

Comment: Swift 2.2: try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to add the Objective-C answer:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:@"AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient" error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setActive:true error:nil];
```

I can confirm this also worked in Sprite Kit when using [SKAction playSoundFileNamed: ] for my sound effects.

Comment: The question is tagged "swift". No need to provide an answer in another language.

Comment: Are there people who cannot translate Objective-C into Swift instantly? For any decent developer, an answer in Objective-C answers the question.

Comment: @gnasher729 The point is not what 'decent' developers are able to do or not - it is "don't answer in Java to a Ruby question" and also "don't modify a question just to make it inline with your answer". This is being discussed [on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311285/user-adding-off-topic-tag-to-question-to-make-it-inline-with-their-answer).

Comment: I appreciate when people post both the swift and obj-c answers, I up-voted